# list all files in a directory where file created date matches week no? vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to list all files in a directory where the files created date falls under the matching week number for that date?

For example:

In cell H7, i have week number 50.

In my directory i have the following files:

```
A.pdf - Created 15/12/2016
B.pdf - Created 15/12/2016
C.pdf - Created 01/12/2016
```

Only the files created on the 15th december should be listed, since these fall under week 50. For some reason, my code does nothing and doesn't list the files or produce an error.

```
Sub Example1()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
If Dir("G:\STOCK\(3) Promotions\Allocations\" & Range("N7").Value & "\" & Range("B7").Value & "\WK " & Range("H7").Value & "\" & client, vbDirectory) <> "" Then


Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("G:\STOCK\(3) Promotions\Allocations\" & Range("N7").Value & "\" & Range("B7").Value & "\WK " & Range("H7").Value & "\")


i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
If Application.WeekNum(objFile.DateCreated) Like Range("H7").Value Then


'print file PG
    Cells(i + 12, 1) = Range("N7").Value
    'print file Month
    Cells(i + 12, 5) = Range("H7").Value

    'print file Year
    Cells(i + 12, 9) = Range("B7").Value

    'print file name
    Cells(i + 12, 13) = objFile.Name

    'print file path
    Cells(i + 12, 18) = "=hyperlink(""" & objFile.Path & """)"

    i = i + 1
    End If
Next objFile

Else

MsgBox "No Results Were Found."
End If
End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: The value returned by the `Weeknum` function for 15 Dec 2016 = 51, not 50.  Look up information about the different return values for `WEEKNUM` and `ISOWEEKNUM`

Comment: @Moacir thank you for your suggestion. As Ron Rosenfeld said, This does seem to kind of be working. I am having to enter week number 51 in order for it to show any results. I think it is starting the week on another day rather than monday. But i want the week number to start on monday, can this be done?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between the Excel `WEEKNUM` function and whatever convention you are using to determine your weeknumber.  You are probably using the ISO Weeknumber convention, and you will have to compute it similarly in VBA.  For VBA, look at the DatePart function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are using the ISO convention for weeknumbers, wherein week 1 is the first week of the year containing four days, and weeks start on Monday.

So you want to replace your Application.Weeknumber comparison line with:

```
If DatePart("ww", objFile.DateCreated, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = ...
```

IF you are using a different convention to compute the Weeknumber, you should be able to incorporate it into the `DatePart` arguments.

Comment: thanks this works great. Is there anyway i could amend this function also to check whether the day of the created file date was a tuesday?

Comment: @Bing.Wong  Sure, just use the appropriate `Interval` argument.  Although it would probably be simpler to just use the `Weekday` function.